# how to get uitextfield text from one view controller from another view controller using setmathod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want get string from one view controller to another view controller i done like this in android

```
public void setName(double name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

like wise .i'm new to iPhone how can i code in this method in iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// ViewController_A.h
@interface ViewController_A : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *info;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *info;
```

Then to set the UITextField:

```
NSString *someString = @"blah";
[[viewController_A info] setText:someString];
```